# Rubber and Amazon EC2 hosting issue (Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: root)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-ec2, capistrano, rubber

I want to host my ruby on rails application on Amazon EC2 server. I am following [Rubber and Amazon EC2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/347-rubber-and-amazon-ec2?view=asciicast) railcast on Ubuntu. When I execute `cap rubber:create_staging` command, its showing error something like this --

```
* 2013-06-19 17:00:53 executing `rubber:setup_remote_aliases'
servers: ["production.ginfy.com", "www.ginfy.com", "foo.ginfy.com", "ginfy.ginfy.com", "temple.ginfy.com", "ibetter.ginfy.com"]
connection failed for: www.ginfy.com (Timeout::Error: execution expired), ibetter.ginfy.com (Timeout::Error: execution expired), temple.ginfy.com (Timeout::Error: execution expired), ginfy.ginfy.com (Timeout::Error: execution expired), production.ginfy.com (Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: root)
```

I already check [google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubber-ec2/By2xhrm7jJQ) and [github issue](https://github.com/rubber/rubber/issues/269) regarding this issue, but nothing worked for me.

Any idea Why I am getting this error? I can't figure out problem. Please help.

**UPDATE :**

I successfully hosted my rails application on Amazon. Now I want to know that How to run seeds.rb on Amazon. Is there any way to open console on Amazon ?

Here I mentioned my problem - [How to run seed.rb file on Amazon ec2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17231741/how-to-run-seed-rb-file-on-amazon-ec2) [Solved]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep!! Amazon Ruby on Rails hosting done. Now its working fine. [Rubber](http://railscasts.com/episodes/347-rubber-and-amazon-ec2?view=asciicast) is not worked for me.

I am using Elastic Beanstalk (eb) for hosting by following this tutorial

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Ruby_rails.html

Its very easy to integrate and fast in deployment also :)