# How to run seed.rb file on Amazon ec2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Recently I hosted my Ruby on Rails application on Amazon EC2 using [Elastic Beanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Ruby_rails.html). Everything works fine except my seeds.rb file. My seeds.rb file is not executed at the time of hosting. I am using [ActiveAdmin](http://activeadmin.info/documentation.html) also and I define first admin on my seeds.rb file.

How can I create first admin user on Amazon by rails console? ***Is there any way to open Rails Console on Amazon EC2 ?*** I am trying to do this using putty but don't know how to do this. Please give me some pointers..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create keypair to access the amazon instance(which i think you already have). Make sure that ssh access is enabled in the current selected security group.

You can connect to the amazon instance using

`ssh -i path/to/keypair.pub ec2-user@ec2-an-ip-address.compute-1.amazonaws.com`

Then cd into the app directory and run  `bundle exec rake db:seed RAILS_ENV='staging'` assuming that you're running the app in staging environment.

Comment: I successfully login through SSH. Now it showing like this `[ec2-user@ip-10-28-206-117 ~]$` but I don't know my app directory path. I try to run `ls` command but nothing is showing.

Comment: Not working, showing error `-bash: cd: /var/www: No such file or directory`

Comment: what server you're using? passenger?

Comment: check these 2 directories.. `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` and `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` you will be able to find the config files in either these 2 dirs.. From there you can check the location of the app

Comment: etc directory working but after that No such file and directory found.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32143/discussion-between-shreshtt-bhatt-and-benchwarmer)

Comment: Is there any way to pull db from heroku and dumb it to my amazon database ?

Answer (score 8):

Are you not supposed to do something like this?

```
# .ebextensions/bundles_container.config
container_commands:
  01-bundle-install:
    command: "bundle install"
    leader_only: true
  02-bundle-db-migrate:
    command: "bundle exec rake db:migrate"
    leader_only: true
  03-bundle-db-seed:
    command: "bundle exec rake db:seed RAILS_ENV='staging'"
    leader_only: true
```

You can also pass parameters if needed, or combine all those commands with "cmd1 && cmd2".

Answer (score 1):

In case you're here and the above solutions didn't work for you.

Apart from using the command provided in this answer above by benchwarmer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17232607/1216245

I had to run the seed command providing env vars for the master key and all rds settings.

`bundle exec rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_MASTER_KEY=<your master key> RDS_HOSTNAME=<your rds hostname> RDS_PASSWORD=<...> RDS_USERNAME=<...> RDS_DB_NAME=<...> RDS_PORT=<...>`

And it worked, finally :)

You can check all this in the Configuration panel for your environment in the AWS console (dashboard).